# in Dropbox: how to list all members with whom I share files/folders?

Tags: dropbox, audit

I own a dropbox team account with thousands of nested shared folders.
Does dropbox web or dropbox desktop can produce list all users with access to these files & folders?

for example,
if my files
user-A shared folder-M with user-X
user-A shared file-N with user-B
user-B shared folder-L with user-X
user-A shared file-P with user-Y
user-C did not share anything.

I would like to get a list of this sort:
user-x:  folder-M:,
user-B:  file-N:
folder-L: user-X
file-P:   user-Y

(hovering one by one, to see the member's tooltip bubble, is impractical: tedious, time consumning & error prone)